# Angularjs object-property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this [Angular Module](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-multiple-select) but I can not get the work with nested data.

Here is my [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/08432JUMCjj6Poqb2UP4?p=preview) my output shows country when using `object-property="country` but when I try to show only states, it doesn't work.

```
      <div class="mrg-top50">
    <label>1. Autocomplete field - options list as array of objects</label>
    <multiple-autocomplete ng-model="skills" object-property="country" suggestions-arr="skillsList"></multiple-autocomplete>
    <label>Selected Model Value :          <br />
    </label>
   {{skills}}
</div>
```

Comment: You could create a new variable in your controller to load the states instead of trying to access it from an object property

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do it in your fiddle like this:

```
    <multiple-autocomplete ng-model="skills" object-property="labels" suggestions-arr="skillsList[0].states"></multiple-autocomplete>
```

Though this is really dependent on the [0] index , which means only useful when you have just one element in the given array like in the given example.

Comment: Thank you, this will work just find, since I have only one index element in the array.

Comment: Glad it helped.